# Setting multiple properties at once in an XPO Object

Tags: c#, devexpress, xaf, xpo

I've been experimenting with C# and DevExpress and came across a situation for which I cannot find a simple solution.

I've got three objects:

- Book
- Author
- Series

1. A `Book` has a collection of `Author`s (Many-to-Many)
2. An `Author` has a Collection of `Book`s (Many-to-Many)
3. A `Series` has two collections; `Books` and `Authors`
4. Both `Book` and `Author` have a `Series` collection

My problem is that whenever I add a `Book` to a `Series`, the `Author`(s) of that `Book` should also be added to the `Series`.

```
[Association("SeriesBooks")]
public XPCollection<Book> Books => GetCollection<Book>(nameof(Books));

[Association("SeriesAuthors")]
public XPCollection<Author> Authors
{
    get { return GetCollection<Author>("Authors"); }
}
```

I've considered the following:

- Use the `OnSaving` event
- Adding a setter to my associations
- Using the `AfterConstruction`

But since I'm a beginner, I haven't been able to actually get anything out of this.

I'd be glad with all the help you can offer.

Comment: you just insert a code with book and author please provide the code which causes your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't have any experience with DevExpress, but if you really wanted a prop for the authors in the series class I would create a read-only prop that reads the Authors from the list of the books.  Something like:

```
public List<Author> Authors { 
        get {
            Books.SelectMany(x => x.Authors).ToList();
        } 
    }
```

It would eliminate the work involved in mainatining a seperated list of Authors.  Any change to any of the books included in the series, including addition and removal of books themselves, or any changes to a books authors, would automatically be reflected in the Series without any other code.

Comment: what about that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66647272/threadsafedatalayer-and-idatalayer-devexpress-xpo-cant-map-classinfo-to-same-ta  can you answer it please